# Qt(PySide) Filtering Rows using ProxyModel

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qabstracttablemodel

Hey I am trying build a table with a multiple filtering functions on top of each other. I have already figured out how to filter rows with search strings using RexExp and QSortFilterProxy on top of QAbstractTableModel. But I also would like the QSortFilterProxy to filter for row indices.But I could not figure out how to do it.
So instead of:

`search = QtCore.QRegExp(text,QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive, QtCore.QRegExp.Wildcard)
self.ProxyModelSelect.setFilterRegExp(search)`

I would like to have smth like(method totaly madeup):

```
self.ProxyModelSelect.rowFiltering(rowIndBegin,rowIndEnd)
```

So that it hides the range of rows from the view. I cannot use QTableView.setRowHidden function cause when the table indices change with sorting everything gets messed up. Need to do it with proxy model or inside the base model.

Comment: It's difficult to judge without seeing a more complete code example but... assuming you're correctly mapping the indexes to/from the source model you may also have to make use of [QPersistentModelIndex](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpersistentmodelindex.html)